# How to get ORDER BY to output alphabetically when looking for the cheapest item(s)

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by

I have a table that looks like this:

```
     Products

| id |   name  | price |
|  1 | peaches |   3   |
|  2 | oranges |   3   |
|  3 | lemons  |   3   |
|  4 | apricots|   3   |
```

I need to be able to find the cheapest product on the list + the price but if they are all the same price then just output the one of the cheapest in alphabetical order. Which in this case would be `apricots 3`.

The query I wrote worked for all cases apart from this specific one in which there are more than 1 of the same "cheapest" price.

```
SELECT name, MIN(price)
FROM Products
ORDER BY name ASC, price
```

In this case, it's outputting `peaches 3` because it's the first item on the list. How can I get it to output the variable in alphabetical order when the `MIN(price)` is the same across all the variables?

Comment: Do you mean something like `SELECT MIN(name), price FROM products GROUP BY price ORDER BY price;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select *
from products
order by price, name
limit 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know about "limit" but it helped. Changed it a bit to `SELECT name, price` but otherwise was the same as you wrote. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
SELECT name, MIN(price)
FROM Products
ORDER BY price,name
```